# Notification in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, notifications

Will the thread give up the monitor immediately as soon as the notify() method is invoked like as it happens in wait(). Or when the notify() is invoked, will the monitor be released after the execution of the method is completed.

To which state will the thread move into when notify() is invoked. Waiting or Blocked state ?

Answer (score 0):

The thread owning the monitor will continue to hold the monitor in case of `notify()`.

`notify()`/`notifyAll()` just informs waiting thread that they can optain the lock again. Once a thread obtains the monitor it will exit the `wait()` method and continue.

To sum up: Thread involving `notify()`/`notifyAll()` will stay on `RUNNING` state as soon as the lock releases naturally (out of synchronized block/method).

The goal of notification is just to authorize waiting threads a future chance to get the lock as soon as this one is available.

Answer (score 0):

A thread holds the monitor for an object as long as it is *synchronized* on that object.  A notified thread will move to the `BLOCKED` state, and will obtain the monitor once the owning thread releases it *by leaving the synchronized block/method* that previously held the monitor.

For example, if thread A is blocking on a call to `lock.wait()` and thread B calls `lock.notify()`, thread A will leave the `WAITING` state and enter the `BLOCKING` state**, however thread A will not resume execution (i.e. enter the `RUNNABLE` state) until thread B leaves the `synchronized` block for `lock`.

> ** Assumes there are no other threads waiting on `lock` since the *order* that threads are notified is not guaranteed, which is why you should use `notifyAll()` as a rule (unless you know what you're doing and have a good reason not to).

Using code:

```
public class ThreadStateTest {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            new Thread(new RunnableTest()).start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("this will print first");
                lock.wait();
                System.out.println("this will print third");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    private static class RunnableTest implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("this will print second");
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("this will print fourth");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```